# how to create Amazon EMR cluster from the command line in Ubuntu?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

how to create Amazon EMR cluster from the command line in Ubuntu? I have the private key,access key and the pem file?....Can anyone guide me as how to run the word count example from the command line

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS command line tools (CLI) for this.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

Once these are installed, you have to configure the tool using 'aws configure' command and enter priate key, access key.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

You will also need to enter the region where your EMR cluster (and other resources) will be launched.

To create cluster, the 'create-cluster' command need to be used.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/create-cluster.html

You dont need the pem file for these steps.

Once the cluster is launched, you can run the word count demo as a 'step'.  You can add word count demo as a 'step'

Starting a cluster and running a hadoop job (a script in this case): 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html

Some examples of add-steps is in this section for an already running cluster:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html